# How to query MySQL for two tables if the common attribute changes to different attribute when some activity is performed

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables like Profile and Unsubs, email is the common attribute between them. 
Profile table has three columns i.e email, dontemail and optedincity.

And in unsubs table, I have email, optedoutcity, status_ind.

If an email is optedout out of New York city, then an entry will be made in unsubs table suppose same email is optedout from all the cities the opted in then in unsubs table status_ind will change to 0 and in Profile table email will be marked as optedout date+email and dontemail field will gets updated then in this case if I want to query how many are opted out for only particular city not all cities.

```
Select A.email,b.optedoutcity from Profile A, Unsubs B where A.email=B.email
```

Note if any email is optedout from all the cities, then the email will become null and dontemail column will be changed to email.

In this how to write query to pull exact data optedout for New York city only not for all cities?

Comment: You're looking to `JOIN` two tables together.

Comment: Please show sample data in tabular format, indented by four or more spaces.  Then, show us the expected output.